# env: mysql: No such file or directory after `wp import`

Tags: wordpress, mamp-pro, wp-cli

I'm trying to import a database locally using `wp db import databasename.sql` but I get the following error: `env: mysql: No such file or directory`. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 15):

I resolved this by changing my $PATH, run this in command or update your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: Just did this and restarted the terminal on MacOs Sierra. Did not work for me.

Comment: Worked on Mac OS 10.15.7. only after editing `/etc/paths` and adding `/usr/local/mysql/bin` on a new line, then saving and restarting the Terminal. Now I can do things like 'wp db check'.

Answer (score 13):

The above didn't help me. I fixed it by adding this to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/
```

Comment: The difference between your command here and my command above is that you are running MAMP - which is why my vanilla mysql $PATH would not have worked in your case.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running Desktop Server, which uses XAMPP, your command that needs to be added to `.bash_profile` with the following command is:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin
```

Once you add that, you should be able to use `wp db import` (and not needing to use the wp-cli portal the Desktop Server provides; which wasn't working consistently for me).